# how to resolve json validation error in mlab?

Tags: json, mongodb, validation, mlab

I have this document which nicely uploads to robomongo but in mlab(mlab.com)it is showing JSON validation error.
Specifically ,"We encountered an error while parsing your JSON. Please check your syntax (e.g. ensure you are using double quotes around both your field names and values) and try again. " is making me nervous.
please check the document [here](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cbff4e1c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be an array of JSON documents, not a single JSON document, which is what the mLab JSON document editor expects. In other words, an array is not a valid JSON document, even though its elements may be valid JSON documents.

Comment: Yes,you are right.I added individual collections to successfully save it to mlab.Thanks for your answer.